# $(document).ready(function () $ is not defined

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc, kendo-grid, kendo-asp.net-mvc

I'm working on asp.net mvc and using Kendo UI grid control for data retrieving, using these functionality for another application working fine problem not in code. All JavaScript and Kendo grid ui reference including when i run the application i face these error

> $(document).ready(function () $ is not defined 
>   List:178 Uncaught TypeError: $(...).kendoDatePicker is not a function

multiple time. when i click on error they show me error on this lines

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#StartDate").kendoDatePicker();
});
```

I add assembly on reference but noting fruitful.

Comment: Make sure jQuery is loaded before your script

Comment: You need to reference jquery in your html code before that script.

Comment: Show your reference jquery in your html code

Comment: Ensure jQuery loaded before any required script, either by bundling (`Scripts.Render`) or use src attribute on script tag.

Comment: JQuery is Loaded but facing these error
List:178 Uncaught TypeError: $(...).kendoDatePicker is not a function

Comment: @HassanAbbas — Incomplete question will never help the cause..

Comment: Make sure `kendo.all.ui.js` and other related Kendo UI JS loaded properly. See http://www.telerik.com/forums/newbie-kendodatepicker-is-not-a-function for details.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This says that, missing jQuery source.

You should add jQuery source between head tags:

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js">
```

References must be in head tag following order:

```
<head>
    <title></title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles/kendo.common.min.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles/kendo.default.min.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles/kendo.default.mobile.min.css" />

    <script src="js/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/kendo.all.min.js"></script>
</head>
```

Comment: write under  <head > tag, but facing same issue 
List:178 Uncaught TypeError: $(...).kendoDatePicker is not a function

Comment: You should also add kendoDatePicker source

Comment: @HassanAbbas load scripts in following order: jQuery, Kendo, YourScripts

Comment: @HassanAbbas, check your reference between head tags, I've edited my solution